# The probability of rolling a <tolerance interval> in $n$ rolls

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Apologies in advance for the lack of technical language.

I have some distribution for the probability of observing the random variable, $X$, with some value. I want to know how to compute the probability of observing a combination of values of $X$ lying within certain intervals. Hopefully my image below can help explain:

[image]

In the image above, we have 5 trials (represented by green and purple lines). Before the experiment started, we designated which intervals will be 'success' intervals... the rest will be 'failure' intervals. We obtained 3 values of $X$ that lay within these intervals, but also 2 values of $X$ that lay outside these intervals. Obviously, as you increase the number of trials, you increase the likelihood that you get a match for all three intervals.

I want to know how to compute the probability of getting a match in some designated intervals, given I know the p.d.f. and the number of trials I am allowed to carry out.

Similar to $$P_1(x,y) = 1 - \big(1 - \frac1x\big)^y$$ in the case of

> What is the probability of rolling a $2$ (for example) in $y$ rolls?

You don't need to necessarily 'give me the answer', but I would just as much appreciate to be directed to the resource that would teach me how to do such a thing. (Sorry, I am a math noob!)

Thank you so much!

Comment: If you have the pdf and the range you're interested in, you just have to integrate the pdf over the range.

Comment: Right, that tells me the probability of a single trial lying within the interval. But what about the probability of observing a combination of pre defined intervals over several trials?

Comment: If the trials are independent...

Comment: @Fimpellizieri In other words... What is the probability of getting a trial in this interval AND this other interval AND this other-other interval in 5 trials?

Comment: Are you adding the rolls and asking the chance the sum is within a range?  The [normal approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation) is your friend if there are a fair number of rolls.

Comment: Hi Ross, no the rolls are not added. Imagine a 6 sided unfair die where each side has some unequal probability. What is the chance of rolling a 2, a 4 and a 6 in 5 trials? Perhaps that is a better analogy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the trials are independent, I think this becomes more of a combinatorics problem than a probability one.

Let the probability of falling in the $i$-th range for $i\in\{1,2,3\}$ be $p_i$ and let $p_0 = 1-\sum_{1\leqslant i \leqslant 3} p_i$ be the probability that a trial fails.

Let an *outcome* be a sequence of $n$ trials, and observe that with regard to the result of each trial, order matters.
Each outcome corresponds to a solution of the equation

$$x_0 + x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = n,\tag{1}$$

where the $x_i$ are non-negative integer.
Here, the $x_i$ represents how many trials fell into each range.

By [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), the number of solutions to this equation is $\binom{n+3}{3}$.
Of course, different outcomes may correspond to the same solution (remember that order matters.
For each solution to the equation, there are

$$a(x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3) = \binom{n}{x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3}$$

different outcomes that correspond to it.
Hence, the probability that an outcome corresponds to a particular solution of our equation is $a(x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3)p_0^{x_0}p_1^{x_1}p_2^{x_2}p_3^{x_3}$.

---

Now, we are interested only in outcomes for which each range $i=1,2,3$ contains at least on trial.
We of course must have $n\geqslant 3$.
These outcomes correspond to solutions of equation $(1)$, except now we require that $x_1,x_2,x_3\geqslant 1$.
Equivalently, they correspond to solutions of $y_0 + y_1 + y_2 + y_3 = n-3$, where each $y_i$ is a non-negative integer.

The number of solutions to this equation is $\binom{n}{3}$.
Of course, different outcomes (order matters) may correspond to the same solution.
For each solution to the equation, there are

$$b(y_0,y_1,y_2,y_3) = \binom{n}{y_0,y_1+1,y_2+1,y_3+1}$$

different outcomes that correspond to it. Hence, the probability that an outcome corresponds to a particular solution of our equation is $b(y_0,y_1,y_2,y_3)p_0^{y_0}p_1^{y_1+1}p_2^{y_2+1}p_3^{y_3+1}$.

It follows that the probability that an outcome corresponds to *some* solution of our equation is

$$p_1p_2p_3\sum_{y_0+y_1+y_2+y_3 = n - 3}b(y_0,y_1,y_2,y_3)p_0^{y_0}p_1^{y_1}p_2^{y_2}p_3^{y_3}. \tag{2}$$

You can open this up into nested sums conditioning on the value of each variable, but it's a bit of an ugly process.

---

Another way to approach this would be perhaps with generating functions.
Consider the symbolic product

$$(p_0+p_1+p_2+p_3)^n,\tag{3}$$

(do not simplify it to $1^n$) and think of it as an ordered product.
An outcome in this context can be thought of as choosing one of the $p_i$ in each factor, where choosing $p_i$ in the $j$-th factor corresponds to the $j$-th trial falling in the $i$-th range.

In the expanded product $(3)$, each monomial $c\cdot p_0^{x_0}p_1^{x_1}p_2^{x_2}p_3^{x_3}$ encodes how many trials fell into each range.
Notice of course that we must necessarily have $x_0 + x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = n$.
In other words, each monomial corresponds to a solution of $(1)$.

Moreover and perhaps unsurprisingly, the coefficient $c$ of each such monomial is precisely $a(x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3)$, see [multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem).
Each coefficient counts the number of different ways (order matters!) we could have chosen the $p_i$ to end up in that monomial.

Now, all that's left is to discard the monomials where $p_1$, $p_2$ or $p_3$ are missing: these correspond to outcomes where at least one of these ranges contain no trials.
At this point, plugging in the actual values of $p_i$ into the resulting expression $($which will be precisely $(2))$ will yield the numerical value of the probability sought.

Comment: Thank you for this very in depth answer. I will study this today at work!

Comment: Very inspiring to read through this and see how your brain developed the model... You're awesome!

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to have helped.